# value assigned to global variable in event handler method not reproduced in another method

Tags: java, event-handling, serial-port, scope

I'm working on a java program that accepts serial input and uploads the received data on a COSM server. The global variable that stores the data received from the serial port does not reproduce that value in the method used to update COSM.Could some one please tell me what's wrong with this?
I've even used a global queue object before but when remove is called on the queue object in the update method `NullPointerException` is thrown.

```
public synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent)//Event handler for serial communication 
{

    if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) 
    {
        try {

        val = input.read(); 

        this.update(78164);  

    } catch (PachubeException e) {
        // If an exception occurs it will print the error message from the
        // failed HTTP command
        System.err.println(e.errorMessage);
        //System.out.println("Main method");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
        //  System.out.println("Main method");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        //   System.out.println("Main method");
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}
```

`val` is the global variable. When called in `update` method the value of `val` is zero or 20 (the value with `val` was initialized in its definition).
here's the implementation of the update method:

```
private void update(int feedid) throws PachubeException, IOException ,Exception
{

    Feed f = this.pachube.getFeed(feedid);

    System.out.println("updating ...");

    f.updateDatastream(8345, (double) val);
    f.updateDatastream(6274, (double) val);
    f.updateDatastream(1044, (double) val);
    //   f.updateDatainputDatastream((f.getData(), in, out, true));
    //System.out.println(val);    
    System.out.println("updated");
}
```

Comment: Show us how update() is implemented, and where and how val is declared.

Comment: The `NullPointerException` is throwing because `f` might not have been initialized . Check if `pachube.getFeed(feedid)` is returning reference to an instance of `Feed` class.

Comment: I don't think that's a problem because when data is assigned to the queue object in the update method itself that value is displayed in the output console

Comment: Have you assured yourself by checking it using `System.out.println(f==null);`

Comment: System.out.println(f==null); returns false

Comment: i've tried it another way...the COSM server is repeatedly updated via the `update` method through `Timer` and `TimerTask` object.That didn't work either though

Answer (score 1):

i found the answer to this problem myself.The synchronized specifier in the signature of the serialEvent method prevented any other thread from accessing the val variable . I removed it and it's working perfectly now.